# MySQL self inner joining and seaching in it

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am facing some problems in an apparently simple search script. I have the folowing MySQL table structure:

```
id_product | name_product | has_choice | choice_id
2            Coca-Cola      1            0
3            Fanta          0            2//the id_product of Coca-Cola
4            Sprite         0            2//the id_product of Coca-Cola
```

What i want to acheive after the inner join(includeing concatenating) is this:

```
id_product | name_product           | has_choice | choice_id
3            Coca-Cola of Fanta       0            2
4            Coca-Cola of Sprite      0            2
```

Notice the ids of the products ar the preveious choices id's. Also the main product(for wich are those choices, has been omitted).Also the has_choice column indicates that the product does/doesn't have choices. 
After this is done i will simple search in the resulted elements.
I've been struggling on this problem for two days. Is anyone able to help me in this problem? I'd be grateful. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you probably meant *Fanta of Coca-Cola* not vice versa.

```sql
SELECT p.id_product, 
       CONCAT(p.name_product, ' of ', p1.name_product) name_product, 
       p.has_choice, 
       p.choice_id
  FROM products p JOIN products p1
    ON p.choice_id = p1.id_product
```

*Note in that particular case `INNER JOIN` eliminates the need in `has_choice` to get products that are choices of parent products.*

Output:

```
| ID_PRODUCT |        NAME_PRODUCT | HAS_CHOICE | CHOICE_ID |
-------------------------------------------------------------
|          3 |  Fanta of Coca-Cola |          0 |         2 |
|          4 | Sprite of Coca-Cola |          0 |         2 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/99877/5)** demo.

**UPDATE1** To get list of all products wether they are choices of product or not you need to use `LEFT JOIN`. To search in product names both parent product and choices use appropriate aliases of tables in `WHERE` clause.

```sql
SELECT p.id_product,
       CASE WHEN p1.id_product IS NULL THEN
           p.name_product
       ELSE
           CONCAT(p.name_product, ' of ', p1.name_product) 
       END name_product, 
       p.has_choice, 
       p.choice_id
  FROM products p LEFT JOIN products p1  -- use LEFT JOIN here
    ON p.choice_id = p1.id_product
 WHERE p.has_choice = 0                  -- filter out parent products
   AND (p.name_product  LIKE '%a%'     -- search in product name
        OR
        p1.name_product LIKE '%a%') -- search in product name of a parent product
```

*`CASE` in that query allows to have plain product name for products that are not choices.*

Output:

```
| ID_PRODUCT |        NAME_PRODUCT | HAS_CHOICE | CHOICE_ID |
-------------------------------------------------------------
|          3 |  Fanta of Coca-Cola |          0 |         2 |
|          4 | Sprite of Coca-Cola |          0 |         2 |
|          5 |               Axion |          0 |         0 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5a118/4)** demo.

Comment: Thanks. Got it worikng, but now im facing a new problem. i cannot searc in the newly concatenated name...

Comment: @VictorBojica You're welcome :) Please explain what kind of search are you trying to do.

Comment: also if i have products that i dont have choices for, they are not shown :(

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8fc5a/2/0 i want to have a simple search that will search throung my products and also my choices. The problem was that when i searched for example coca-cola i would only get coca-cola as a simple product, instead of getting all of coca-cola's choices; the product should be shown simple(with no choices concatenated) only when there are no choices.

Comment: @VictorBojica See updated answer. It should address both issues.

Answer (score 2):

This query [should do it](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/25fe9/9).

```
SELECT t1.id_product, 
       Concat(Concat(t2.name_product, ' of '), t1.name_product) AS 
       `name_product`, 
       t1.has_choice, 
       t1.choice_id 
FROM   tbl1 AS t1 
       JOIN tbl1 AS t2 
         ON t1.choice_id = t2.id_product;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to join the table to itself.

Try this:

```
SELECT id, CONCAT(table.name_product, ' of ', table2.name_product), table.has_choice, table.choice_id
FROM table
JOIN table ON (table.id_product = table.choice_id) AS table2
```